# ¿habra alguna manera de acortar codigo html en mi class de photo-gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, script

Estoy haciendo un albun de fotos con HTML pero son muchas fotos que tengo que agregar. cómo se podrá formar un algún tipo carousel o a cortar código HTML, porque creo que va hacer muchas líneas por cada foto que estaré agregando son como 20 fotos, creo que también se puede usar un script dentro hacer un for, y llamar a todas las fotos del 1 al N° Numero, pero no sé cómo realizarlo. En mi clase phot-gallery, solamente llamo a todas las fotos cada una. Se agradece la ayuda:)

```
 <div class="photo-gallery">
<div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
        <h2 class="text-center">Galeria</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Nunc luctus in metus eget fringilla. Aliquam sed justo ligula. Vestibulum nibh erat, pellentesque ut laoreet vitae. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row photos">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/1.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/1.JPG"></a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/2.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/2.JPG"></a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/3.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/3.JPG"></a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/4.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/4.JPG"></a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/5.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/5.JPG"></a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/6.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/6.JPG"></a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/7.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/7.JPG"></a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item"><a href="img/proyecto_costP/6.JPG" data-lightbox="photos"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/6.JPG"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Duplicada y anteriormente cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/567942/263200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro, es tal como tú dices. Puedes agregar un script con un for de esta manera:

(Es lo que considero más sencillo para tu caso)

```html
 <div class="photo-gallery">
<div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
        <h2 class="text-center">Galeria</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Nunc luctus in metus eget fringilla. Aliquam sed justo ligula. Vestibulum nibh erat, pellentesque ut laoreet vitae. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row photos">
      <script>
         for(let i=1; i<=7; i++){
           document.write(
           `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item">
               <a href="img/proyecto_costP/${i}.JPG" data-lightbox="photos">
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="img/proyecto_costP/${i}.JPG">
               </a>
           </div>`);
         }
      </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

No sé si será necesaria una explicación, pero aquí va:

1. Un for de 1 a 7
2. con document.write imprimimos un texto en el documento HMTL
3. Usamos [Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (las comillas invertidas) para ingresar fácilmente HTML como texto
4. Para concatenar una variable (en este caso `i`) en el texto usamos ${i}

Comment: vale pa gracias, porque igual tengo que colocar varios albunes, y colocar varias fotos y seria mucha lineas de codigo thanks :)